# Setting DATETIME to automatically go into database table

Tags: php, sql

I have set my database field to `DATETIME`, and when a user submits the form I want to automatically insert the current date/timestamp. How do I do this?

So far I have..

```
INSERT INTO expenses(user_id, amount, currency, type, description, project_id, filename)
VALUES("30","55","2","6","jult","30",DATETIME,"P")
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOW()` instead of `DATETIME` on your query.

**Sidenote:**
Also, you will face an error on query as you are passing just **7** columns, but you are inserting **8** values.

Comment: yes thanks, i discovered this and got it changed :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a column in your database to store your datetime.

Second, rather than using "DATETIME", using [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)("Y-m-d H:i:s") to generate a GMT/UTC datetime or [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to a local time

Answer (score 0):

There's no field name in your query that I can assume is a `DATETIME` field, but you can use [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp), or [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp).

Of course this is assuming you're using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set a default on the row, if you can:

```
CREATE TABLE expenses (
    /* Other row definitions */
    date DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%s', NOW()))
);
```

That way you can omit the row in your insertion statement entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where you have DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot use a volatile function such as `now()` as the default for most columns.  The one exception is for a `timestamp` column.  So the `create table` statement could look like:

```
create table expenses (
    . . .,
    CreatedAt timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```